# Add "listings don't meet your needs?" link that opens a new ask page on meta "jobs" tag already entered

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

As a person goes through the job listings or the company pages I think the bottom of the grid needs something like this:

[image]

In this case, although fictitious, imagine someone typed in `js ninja` and got these results.  As they scroll, they then get to the end where they are provided with instant feedback.  The feedback could come in the form of a meta post with the jobs tag already filled in.

This helps in a few ways: it gets people to help build the site in a more accurate manner, and at the same time you get feedback from your own candidates.

While we are at it, I can imagine some employers actually bumping into this site (remember a candidate could also play the role of an employer; it's happened to me). As they scroll to the bottom, maybe they see the other link to "hire a new candidate".  This link would link to post a job on careers.

Comment: But `looking to hire a candidate` could also be *sign-up first to register as an employer because that is required before you can post a job*? What I mean is: does the link indeed let anyone do that action it promises you based on the link text?

Comment: @rene - Yes it would do as it should do, if you are already a careers employer, which in many many cases you may be, it will redirect you to the careers site and you can post a job.  If you are not registered with careers, well you'd get what you'd expect to get a page that has a "Register Me" link / button on the site.  This is just like 99.9% of all websites right now.

Comment: @rene Careers does currently allow employers to start filling out a job listing even if they're not logged in. You have to log in/sign up in order to purchase or publish though.

Comment: @Laura - That even fits this request much better - thanks!

Comment: There is a 'Post a Job' link at the top right of the screen.

You have a good point about a direct feedback channel. We'll give this one some thought on how/what to implement. I've set this to deferred for now.

Comment: @Des - I already understand the "Post a job" at the top, but UX doesn't work that way.  As you scroll through a list and don't find anything, where did you end up?  You aren't at the top right corner of a page...no mam...eyes go from the top shifting downwards...and as you get to the end of the results where do eyes tend to go?  They go to the bottom right, hence my link "looking to hire a candidate".  Please use this as an opportunity for you guys to get constructive criticism on real end users who use the system.  I'm not pulling this outta my a**, this is natural for not just me but anyone.

Comment: @JonH You're right. That is how the eye processes information.  We're also keeping in mind that the primary user of this page is a developer (candidate) and not an employer who needs to post a job. In any event, we absolutely appreciate (and use) the constructive criticism. Thank you!